# Starting/Stopping a service on Windows 2008 Server from the command line - access denied

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008

I am trying to start a service from the command line using "net start SERVICENAME" and I get an access denied error.

I am an administrator on this server since I am in a domain group that are admins on the server. I **can** start/stop the service from the Services tool.

I am new to 2008/Vista so maybe I am just missing something..

update: 
I did not use "run as administrator". Is this something new in 2008? Where do I find this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Type cmd into the search box in the start menu.
2. Right click on cmd.exe and Run As Administrator.

   You could also create a shortcut to cmd and set the shortcut to run as administrator if this is something you're going to do often.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

> runas /user:administrator net start
>   SERVICENAME

Comment: Double quotes around a multi-word command are needed:  
`runas /user:SOMEDOMAIN\Adminuser "net start <service name>"`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\Administrator cmd
```

To launch another shell with admin privileges.

```
net start SERVICENAME
```

In case you needed to run more than one command as the administrator...